# Magento 2: issue during upgrade magento

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have try to upgrade magento to latest version but when I try after run command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update
```

I get error:

```
Failed to clone git@github.com:EaDesgin/magento2-pdf-generator2.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

  sh: git: command not found
```

Comment: Install [git](https://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your composer version to 2.2.3 in composer.json file as below:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.9",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.9",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.1.*",
        "magento/sample-data-media": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

in above file change

```
"version": "2.1.9",
```

to

```
"version": "2.2.3",
```

also change

```
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.9",
```

to

```
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.3",
```

after changes as per above run below command:

```
composer update
```

Comment: I have delete line  require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update and now work.

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the error displayed in the question.